# Polymer two-way binding between custom elements [example included]

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to make custom element within a custom element and have the inner custom element able to change its value from within and the outer able sync its binding on that change. What can I do to get this working?

I've thoroughly scoured the documentation, but it's very lackluster in this department. I believe [Node.bind()](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/node_bind.html) may be something of interest, but not sure how it would apply in this case.

Here's a simplified test case and plunker demo:

```
  <polymer-element name='test-app'>
       <template>

           First:
           <test-input id='one' value='{{value}}'></test-input>

           <br/>
           <br/>

           Second:
           <test-input id='two' value='{{value}}'></test-input>

           <br/>
           <br/>

           Value:
           {{value}}
       </template>
       <script>
           Polymer({ 
               value: 5
           })
       </script>
   </polymer-element>

   <polymer-element name='test-input'>

       <template>

           <style>
               #val {
                   font-size: 50px;
               }
           </style>

           <div id='val'>{{value}}</div>

           <button on-tap='{{increment}}'>+</button>
           <button on-tap='{{decrement}}'>-</button>

       </template>

       <script>
           Polymer({

               publish: {
                   value: 4
               },
               increment: function() {
                   this.value = this.value + 1;
               },
               decrement: function() {
                   this.value = this.value - 1;
               }
           })
       </script>
   </polymer-element>

   <test-app></test-app>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/KjQ9DusaFg2jp1BTFUde?p=preview

If this was working, the `value` property of the `test-app` parent element should be in sync with both of the `test-input`s `value` property.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to resolve "Attributes on element-name were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23870541/how-to-resolve-attributes-on-element-name-were-data-bound-prior-to-polymer-upgr)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice this warning in the console:

> Attributes on test-input were data bound prior to Polymer upgrading the element. This may result in incorrect binding types.

`test-app` uses `test-input` before Polymer knows about `test-input`. All of an element's dependencies must be declared before that element is declared. Move `test-input` above `test-app` and it works as expected.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ZaIj60S3lAHT18k5T3sn?p=preview

Comment: Ah, thanks for catching that. In my haste, I chalked up the plunker not working as the same reason it's not working in my app. I realize now it's really because of the expression inside the binding that causes it to break: http://plnkr.co/edit/KjQ9DusaFg2jp1BTFUde?p=preview